# How to refresh / reload a view (chart) after data download

Tags: swift3, uiview

I am using SwiftChart on Github (not to be confused w/ SwiftCharts) for charting data. Everything works fine until I downloaded data for the chart.  I call a DispatchGroup after the download to configure the chart, but the chart is always blank.  I thought it was an issue with DispatchGroup till I noticed that without downloading if I configure a basic chart in viewDidAppear() it is also blank.  Yet in viewDidLoad() it works fine.

The chart is a subclassed UIView.  Is there a method to refresh a view?  It seems that after the view is drawn, it will not update and remains blank.

The code to update the chart that works in viewDidLoad:

```
// Simple chart
   let series = ChartSeries([0, 6, 2, 8, 4, 7, 3, 10, 8])
   series.color = ChartColors.greenColor()
   chart.add(series)
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? I'm in a similar position

Comment: Grady... I can't remember exactly, but Swift Charts just didn't work out for me.  I am now using Charts (some fellow named Gindi)  It's a bit more complex, but once you figure it more powerful IMHO.. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts